# How can I remove the file extension from the object name in the build step?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT` is a variable to set compile rules.

```
set("<CMAKE_MY_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> -o <OBJECT> -c <FLAGS> <SOURCE>")
```

This variable is set in `CMake<LANG>Information.cmake`. The source file is build and produces an object file `build/hello_world.o`. CMake is expecting the compiler to produce a different object name.

```
[ 95%] Building object CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/hello_world.my.o
[100%] Linking executable hello_world
[100%] Built target hello_world
```

How can I remove the source file extension `my` from the object name in the build step?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the variable? Have you looked into using CMake's `string(REGEX ... )` [command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/string.html#regular-expressions) to manipulate the contents of this variable?

Comment: this is not a cached variable nor a global variable. I don't think I have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following variable:

`set(CMAKE_<LANG>_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE 1)`

I set this in the file `CMakeLANGInformation.cmake` for a new cmake language.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I cannot find this variable in doc, is this an internal feature ?

Comment: It is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_OUTPUT_EXTENSION.html).  Appending _REPLACE does what you would expect.